# ssrs show text different colour when field matches with another

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, colors, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a requirement to show different text color when one field matches with another three different fields.

I have written below expression,

```
=IIF(
Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!InstitutionBlockLetter.Value, "Green",  
or Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!DegreeBlockLetter.Value, "Orange",
or Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!AwardBlockLetter.Value, "Blue", "No Color")
```

But its not working. When saving this code it gives error.

I am using SSRS report builder.

Comment: Are you reviving an error or is the color change just not occurring?

Comment: @chance-finley When saving this code it gives error.

Comment: where is this code being saved? as an expression, or in the color font expression?

Comment: @chance-finley As color font expression

Answer (score 3):

You can't use IIF with OR like that. IIF just returns a value if the expression is true and another if it's false. You can nest IIFs to get the desired results but using SWITCH is much simpler. Try this... (not tested but should be close enough)

```
=SWITCH
(
Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!InstitutionBlockLetter.Value, "Green",  
Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!DegreeBlockLetter.Value, "Orange",
Fields!OrderBlockLetter.Value = Fields!AwardBlockLetter.Value, "Blue",
True, "Black"
)
```

As switch returns on the first true expression, if all the others fail, the final expression is always True so the "Black" will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually, "No Color" is not a valid font. You either need to pick black (the default color), or white (to give the appreance of there not being text there)

Comment: If I change it to some other color still same issue